# How to create text-shadow in Axure

Tags: styles

### My Goal

Im using [Axure](http://www.axure.com/) for prototyping and I've created widgets which reflect my application UI.

One thing I would like to achieve is the **ability to add text-shadow onto certain elements**, without having to type the same text twice and layer them over each other.

---

### What I've tried so far

I've tried several methods and hacks to get this to work with no luck.
The closest I have got is creating 2 dynamic panels, one which I type the desired text into and then when previewing the protoype, I can click on the element to trigger the onclick event to update the shadow element. Which is far from ideal.

---

### Existing Examples

Im pretty sure this can be achieved as I have seen it done in other peoples Axure libraries.

**For Example:**
http://axutopia.com/axure-widgets-libraries/axure-iphone-widgets-library/

[image: text-shadow-in-axure]

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing in this screenshot is an image, it's not formatted in Axure. Your best bet would be to layer text panels so you get the shadow effect.